# Using Linq to find duplicates but get the whole record

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

So I am using this code

```
    var duplicates = mg.GroupBy(i => new { i.addr1, i.addr2 })
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(g=>g.Key);
    GridView1.DataSource = duplicates;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

to find and list the duplicates in a table based on addr1 and addr2. The only problem with this code is that it only gives me the pair of addr1 and addr2 that are duplicates when i actually want to display all the fields of the records. ( all the fields like ID, addr1, addr2, city, state...)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get all values, you can use `ToList()` on `IGrouping`

```
var duplicates = mg.GroupBy(i => new { i.addr1, i.addr2 })
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                   .Select(g => new {g.Key, Values = g.ToList()});
```

Comment: that is a really good solution...it didnt cross my mind to do the Value = g.Tolist()

Answer (score 8):

You should use `First()` instead of `Key`:

```
var duplicates = mg.GroupBy(i => new { i.addr1, i.addr2 })
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .Select(g => g.First());
```

It returns the first row of each duplicate groups

Comment: Select(g => g.First()); this is not working I am getting an error... .

Comment: Error like below ,  System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.'