# Getting duplicates using Linq on strongly typed table

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm looking for duplicates in a table based on Name, Date and Category all being the same. I want both (or all) of the duplicated rows in my result set. I'm using VS 2008 with .net 3.5. I'm starting with data in a strongly typed table and want to end up with only duplicates on the same table or in a copy of the table. I'm using the data table as the source for a report.

I've spent a lot of time checking out similar questions but have not found an answer.

```
Dim LList as PmtDataTable = PmtList.GroupBy(x => New {x.Name, x.PmtDate, x.Category}) _
                   .Where(x => x.Count() > 1) _
                   .select(x => New {x.key, Values = x.tolist()})
```

I got the syntax from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747265/2559297 but since I'm using old VS it's not working for me. Can you translate this to  VS 2008 with .net 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the keyword **Key**

And you missed the `C#` and `VB.NET` :)  (I am a C# developer).

Try this:

`Dim query = PmtList.GroupBy(Function(x)  New With {Key .Name = x.Name, Key .PmtDate = x.PmtDate, Key .Category = x.Category}) _
                   .Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1) _
                   .Select(Function(x)  New With {.KeyName = x.key, .Count= x.Count()})`

Comment: change `Dim LList as PmtDataTable` to `Dim query` should work

Comment: Somehow I need to get the linq result back to the datatable

Comment: Thanks for the help with the syntax. For that I'm accepting this as the answer. See my answer for how to get it back to the data table.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim.Tang's answer is close. But I need it to feed back to a PmtDataTable. So changed his Select statement to return the groups. Then I get the rows and add the data to a new data table.

```
Dim dupList = PmtList.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .Name = x.Name, _
                                                    Key .PmtDate = x.PmtDate, _ 
                                                    Key .Category = x.Category}) _
                     .Where(Function(y) y.Count() > 1) _
                     .SelectMany(Function(grp) grp)

Dim PmtList2 As New PmtDataTable
For Each rw as PmtRow In dupList
    Dim iRow As PmtRow
    iRow = PmtList2.NewPmtRow
    iRow.ItemArray = rw.ItemArray
    PmtList2.AddPmtRow(iRow)
Next
```